# CAMediaTimingFunctionNameが使えない

Tags: swift, github

Swiftのオープンソースライブラリのfolding-cellというものを使おうとしたんですけど、その際にCAMediaTimingFunctionNameの部分で以下のエラーが出てしまっていてビルドがうまくいきません。

Use of undeclared type 'CAMediaTimingFunctionName'

AppleのDeveloperサイトを見た時にこのクラスは存在しているように思えたので、自分で作成する必要はないと思っているのですが、どうなのでしょうか？？

知っている方がいらっしゃれば教えていただきたいです。また、Swiftのバージョンアップによって使うクラスが変わったということであればそれについても教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

folding-cellのURL
https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell

Comment: ご自身の環境についてきちんと記していただけないでしょうか。`CAMediaTimingFunctionName`と言うデータ型(細かい話ですが「クラス」ではありません)はiOS 12 SDK/Swift 4.2で導入されたものですが、該当のリポジトリはXcode 10用に更新されている(ドキュメントにはXcode 9+と書いてあるのに、Xcode 9.xでも使えるようなコーディングにはなっていないですね)ので、あなたが最新のXcodeを使っていれば、コンパイルできるはずなのですが。

Comment: XCode9の環境があったので試してみましたが、確かにこのエラーが出ますね。XCode10では出ないので、OOPerさんの言う通り素直にXCode10にするべきでしょう。

Comment: どうしてもXCode9でも動かしたい場合は、GitHubの過去のリリースの3.1.5をダウンロードすれば動作するようです。

Comment: OOPerさん、user17014さんありがとうございます。Xcodeをアップデートしてもう一度確かめてみます。